# Setting Up Xen and Network Bridge on Debian 7

Tags: networking, debian, virtualization, xen, bridge

## Setting up Xen and Network Bridges on Debian 7

Hi there. So i am finally going to try out some virtualisation on my new dedicated machine, however i am having some problems / confusion on setting it up, so i will try best to explain my situation, and any help would be much appreciated.

To start, my server has ONE physical network adapter, eth0. The default configuration within /etc/network/interfaces is as follows

---

```
### Hetzner Online AG - installimage
# Loopback device:
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# device: eth0
auto  eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address   144.76.29.149
  broadcast 144.76.29.159
  netmask   255.255.255.224
  gateway   144.76.29.129
  # default route to access subnet
  up route add -net 144.76.29.128 netmask 255.255.255.224 gw 144.76.29.129 eth0

iface eth0 inet6 static
  address 2a01:4f8:191:2094::2
  netmask 64
  gateway fe80::1
```

---

However i also have a second IP allocation i purchased from my host, just to confirm i can successfully setup what i would like to do (Run roughly 3 virtual machines, each on their own external IP address) on my machine

The information for the second allocation is:

---

```
Address 144.76.47.82
Gateway 144.76.47.81
Netmask 255.255.255.248
Broadcast 144.76.47.87
```

---

I have installed bridge-utils as directed in the guide i have been following (  http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Xen_Beginners_Guide#Preparation )

I then add my new bridge using `brctl addbr xenbr0`

This is where i get stuck, or normally break my networking, which means i have to go into recovery and restore it to what it was originally, which is expected as i do not understand how this all works as of yet.

I am confused because i have seen some guides where you need to setup `iface eth0 inet manual` and then configure the static ip on the `iface xenbr0 inet static` and some where it is vice versa. Either way i have attempted has ended up in me breaking my networking as such

So, as a quick summary of what i would like too do:

- I would like to be able to assign each of my virtual machines their own external IP address
- I would like to have the dom0 using my first IP allocation (144.76.29.149) and my second machine (Which i am using as a tester) using my second IP allocation (144.76.47.82)
- I assume i have to use bridge tools to do this correctly? As the Xen guide suggests

I have not been able to find any tutorials which could guide a newbie through this, as i have not used / been into linux networking much, as my machines have always already had it completely configured and ready.

Thanks for any help or articles you point me towards

Answer (score 1):

You want your interfaces file to look like this. Yes, you'll need bridge-utils

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto xenbr0
iface xenbr0 inet static
    bridge_ports eth0
    address   144.76.29.149
    netmask   255.255.255.224
    gateway   144.76.29.129
    post-up route add -net 144.76.29.128 netmask 255.255.255.224 gw 144.76.29.129 eth0
iface xenbr0 inet6 static
    address   144.76.29.149
    broadcast 144.76.29.159
    netmask   255.255.255.224
    gateway   144.76.29.129
```

Now, what you want to do is add a second subnet to your internal machine; you're going to need some more post-up routes for that which is out of my scope. But this should get your Dom0 working and a bridge ready for your DomU.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just wanting to get your feet wet, there is a nice GUI in the Debian repository:

`apt-get install virt-manager`

In particular, note the virtual network configuration bits.  You might try setting up a few virtual machines using the GUI and then try a manual setup again.